# Measuring a DOM node synchronously in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

Say, I want to measure a DOM element [as described in React’s hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) with an additional twist: the result needs to be applied to another element before the browser repaints. As far as I understand, `setState` does not guarantee that the update will be applied immediately unless it’s inside `useLayoutEffect`. However, effects [should not be used for this purpose](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14387) either. What would be the correct approach then?

To sum up, I’d like to achieve the same thing as in the example below, but without `0px` briefly flashing before `setHeight` has any effect.

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example of this in your question.

Comment: @HåkenLid Done.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar concern however from my tests the snippet you've taken from the React docs *does* run before a paint occurs. i.e. it doesn't flash `0px` before rendering the measured height.

Practically speaking, you can prove this using the chrome profiler which will spit out screenshots. Alternatively, you can slow down the callback and see it never paints `0px`.

> NOTE: Debug statements aren't a good way to test this because they will pause JS execution, but allow paints (at least in Chrome).

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) {}
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Theoretically speaking, it has to execute the ref callback *before* paint because DOM refs are available in `useLayoutEffect` which [we know runs before paint](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect).

```
function MeasureExample2() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const nodeRef = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
     if (!nodeRef.current) {
       throw new Error('Expected el'); // Never called
     }
     setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
  });
  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={nodeRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Additionally, [`setState` within `useLayoutEffect` will run synchronously](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17334#issuecomment-1056968834); if it didn't it would make `useLayoutEffect` rather painful as you'd have to imperatively mutate the DOM rather than using React render.

I think therefore React must:

1. Mutate DOM
2. Set DOM refs
3. Execute useLayoutEffect callbacks
4. Execute useEffect callbacks

Where steps 1, 2 and 3 are all synchronous meaning the browser hasn't had the opportunity to paint yet.

Comment: Regarding the "theoretical" part: ref callbacks might be run synchronously, but that doesn’t mean that state updates requested inside those will execute synchronously as well. They may be batched and applied at a later time, even after some other state updates requested after that (e.g., in `useLayoutEffect`) have already been performed.

Comment: Yeh fair point. I think in practice it does but I guess there's no documentation saying they guarantee it -- would be great if React would document this more throughly as measuring a DOM element isn't massively uncommon.

Comment: I think it'd be mad if they stopped scheduling setState synchronously in a callback ref as there's a [lot](https://github.com/react-hookz/web/blob/master/src/useMeasure/useMeasure.ts#L18) of [libraries](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer/blob/master/src/useInView.tsx#L48) which store refs in state because they need a way to bind / unbind events when the ref changes.

Answer (score 0):

Only render the h2 when you have a non-zero height.

```
{height && (<h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>)}
```

you could also use css property visibility: hidden on the entire component until it has been measured.

```
<div style={{visibility: height ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>
  <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
  <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but not ideal: that would mean the layout visibly changes after the initial render.

Comment: In particular, it would look strange if one of the components is hidden while all the others around it are visible.

Comment: It's likely to only take a few milliseconds before it renders.